# How to import a single go file in golang? Unable to import go file

Tags: go, import

Trying to import a file go file but unable to do so.

I have one main file:

```
    main/
      main.go  
      go_single_file.go
```

```
package main

import (
"./go_single_file"
)

func main() {

}
```

and `go_single_file`:

```
package go_single_file

func hello() bool{
return true
}
```

when i try to import `go_single_file` in my main file i get some sort of import error.

I am doing something wrong but not sure what.

If i make a separate package and import it then it works but not if it's in same folder.

Can anyone tell how can i import a go file from same folder.

Comment: You don't import files in Go. Files in the same directory are part of the same package. See https://go.dev/doc/code#Organization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Golang files are [organized](https://go.dev/doc/code#Organization) into subdirectories called packages which enables code reusability.

The naming convention for Go package is to use the name of the directory where we are putting our Go source files. Within a single folder, the package name will be same for the all source files which belong to that directory.

I would recommend you to use go modules and your folders structure should be like this.

```
.
├── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go_single_file
│   └── go_single_file.go
```

In your go_single_file.go you are not using [exported names](https://go.dev/tour/basics/3) for the function hello. So your file inside the `go_single_file/go_single_file.go` would look like this.

```golang
package go_single_file

func Hello() bool{
    return true
}
```

Your main file would like this

```golang
package main

import (
    "module_name/go_single_file"
)

func main() {
   _ = go_single_file.Hello()

}
```